# Using the Master Theorem with merge sort.

Tags: algorithms, sorting

Using the Master theorem, show that merge sort on n objects takes (exactly)(nlogn) comparisons of objects?
Also why is it important to use ceiling function?

I think I know to use case 2, but I'm unsure as to how.

Comment: Hi: i switched the irrelevant tag for relevant tags so that the question gains visibility with those who are familiar with the subject matter. cheers

Comment: Thank you! Sorry I wasn't sure

Comment: [CS SE: Applying the Master Theorem on Merge sort](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/62427/applying-the-master-theorem-on-merge-sort) might help.